# Android get difference in milliseconds between two dates

Tags: java, android, date

I have Integer fields:

currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,currentHour,currentMinute and nextYear,nextMonth,nextDay,nextHour,nextMinute.

How I can get difference between those two spots in time in milliseconds.
I found a way using Date() object, but those functions seems to be depricated, so it's little risky.

Any other way?

Comment: Convert it into long and do substraction

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#getGregorianChange%28%29) to create the date, and take the diff as you otherwise would.

```
GregorianCalendar currentDay=new  GregorianCalendar (currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,currentHour,currentMinute,0);
GregorianCalendar nextDay=new  GregorianCalendar (nextYear,nextMonth,nextDay,nextHour,nextMinute,0);

diff_in_ms=nextDay. getTimeInMillis()-currentDay. getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: well, that helped me when I had to convert a given date format to milliseconds and then calculate time passed. +1

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Calendar` object for `currenDay` and `nextDay`, turn them into longs, then subtract. For example:

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth - 1); // January is 0, Feb is 1, etc.
Calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, currentDay);
// set the year, hour, minute, second, and millisecond
long currentDateInMillis = currentDate.getTimeInMillis();

Calendar nextDate = Calendar.getInstance();
// set the month, date, year, hour, minute, second, and millisecond
long nextDateInMillis = nextDate.getTimeInMillis();

return nextDateInMillis - currentDateInMillis; // this is what you want
```

If you don't like the confusion around the `Calendar` class, you can check out the Joda time library.